# querySelectorAll Event Listener function does not iterate correctly

Tags: javascript, function, loops, dom, dom-events

I am trying to create an eventListener() function on a number of map icons. Each of these map icons have a corresponding span tag with the name of its location.

The idea here is that when a user hovers over an icon, it will trigger an event listener that will toggle the corresponding span tag. There are ten icons in total. Simple enough on paper.

I have managed to iterate using querySelectorAll in that when each icon is hovered over, the event listener fires. However, my issue here is that the actual toggle only works for the first element in the class list. So, if we call the first map icon 'A', when I hover over 'B', 'C', 'D' respectively, instead of showing me **their** span tags, it keeps firing the toggle for 'A' only. I think I am getting an iteration wrong here somewhere.

HTML:

```
<div class="map-icon moreno">
    <span class="map-icon-text">Moreno Valley, CA</span>
</div>

<div class="map-icon dallas">
    <span class="map-icon-text">Dallas, TX</span>
</div>

<div class="map-icon cicero">
    <span class="map-icon-text">Cicero, IL</span>
</div>

<div class="map-icon chattanooga">
    <span class="map-icon-text">Chattanooga, TN</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.map-icon-text {
    transform: scale(0);
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out; }

.map-icon-text-active {
    transform: scale(1);
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out; }
```

JS:

```
const iconText = document.querySelector('.map-icon-text');

function addSpanClass() {
  iconText.classList.add('map-icon-text-active');
}

function removeSpanClass() {
  iconText.classList.remove('map-icon-text-active');
}

const mapIcon = document.querySelectorAll('.map-icon');
for (i = 0; i < mapIcon.length; i++) {
  mapIcon[i].addEventListener('mouseenter', addSpanClass);
  mapIcon[i].addEventListener('mouseleave', removeSpanClass);
}
```

Ultimately, I am pushing the .map-icon-text-active CSS into the span tag to animate and using the eventListener to toggle this action. It works for the div 'moreno' but fails to work for the other locations.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Your event handler is always updating `iconText`, which is `const iconText = document.querySelector('.map-icon-text');`, so it always points to the same element. What is your expected behavior?

Comment: document.querySelectorAll() does not return a single node, it returns a node list. So you will have to iterate and add class to each node.

Comment: @smartdroid OP is already iterating the result from `querySelectorAll`

Comment: @phil OP is iterating it for addEventListener. But not in classlist where the issue is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `const iconText = document.querySelector('.map-icon-text');` is global, so only return the first match on the web page.

For it to work, you want to rely on the event target specificially:

```
function addSpanClass(event) {
  const iconText = event.target.querySelector('.map-icon-text');
  iconText.classList.add('map-icon-text-active');
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer - this worked perfectly. Can I just ask, I've re-written my code but forgot to add 'event' as a param for my function and somehow, it still works. How?

Comment: @DanShafi this is hard to say, it could be many things... Starting with the cache? Maybe your browser is still running an old version of your code. Otherwise maybe some global event variable is declared somewhere else and is reachable from inside your event handler.